# Translating a message to a payload in Scala / Grpc

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

After days of trying and failed, finally I have succeed in implementing both Grpc and Gatling plugins into one project (embarrassingly long time), now I am looking into phiSgr example (again, sorry for this), and I see there is a part as this:

```
message GreetRequest {
    string username = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

and in GrpcExample.scala, he "translate it":

```
  val greetPayload: Expression[GreetRequest] = GreetRequest(name = "World").updateExpr(
    _.username :~ $("username")
  )
```

---

So I just want to know the procedure to translate this chunk:

```
message Device {
   string id = 1[(google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED]
}
```

```
message StartPairingRequest {
   Device device = 1 [(google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED]
}
```

With a body message when I do request

```
{
   "Device": {
       "id": "random text"
   }
}
```

What I have tried to do in .scala file:

```
val greetPayload: Expression[StartPairingRequest] = StartPairingRequest(device = " "theBody" = "random text" ").updateExpr(
_.device:~$("device")
)
```

it seems that my implementation is not right, so I would wish to learn more about this "translating" procedure, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension function `updateExpr` and the operator `:~` are used to construct dynamic payload with the virtual user's [`Session`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/).

Using them requires knowing a concept called lens, which is used in [ScalaPB](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/getting-started).

Those who lack the prior knowledge are strongly recommended to use the Kotlin binding and write your load tests in Kotlin/Java.

---

However the payload described in this question has no dynamic value, and can be constructed simply as:

```
StartPairingRequest(Device("random text"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your instructions for where to learn, may I ask that the sub Json "id" is not mentioned in StartPairingRequest(Device("random text")), does it affect the way the body is passing in ?

Comment: Whether you [name your arguments in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/named-arguments.html) is a syntactic thing. They mean the same either way.

Comment: and one more thing, asked in comment is stupid but I am not sure about the way to pass in the BearerToken, could you give me a little hint where I should start first ?

Comment: https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/67eb5ea196d66db9e26be292df632be82329785a/src/test/scala/com/github/phisgr/example/GrpcExample.scala#L17

Comment: Thanks, I should dive deeper to know more about scala, there isn't much about GRPC for load testing... Hopefully you can be patient a bit for me, deadline is so near :(

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a broken record, you should've started with Kotlin+Gradle.