# Akka GRPC returns "CoordinatedShutdown with reason" while using Gatling - Grpc Plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, akka-grpc

Relating to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228688/translating-a-message-to-a-payload-in-scala-grpc/77247760?noredirect=1#comment136189252_77247760) , I have tried mr.Leung suggestion, and I think the implementation is OK for now, but when compiling, I get this log issue

```
10:21:01.047 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO io.gatling.core.config.GatlingConfiguration$ - Gatling will try to load 'gatling.conf' config file as ClassLoader resource.
10:21:01.522 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
10:21:01.767 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
10:21:01.880 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
10:21:01.880 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 17
10:21:01.882 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
10:21:01.882 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
10:21:01.883 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
10:21:01.883 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
10:21:01.883 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
10:21:01.884 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
10:21:01.885 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @57a49ead
10:21:01.886 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
10:21:01.886 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
10:21:01.902 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 1073741824 bytes (maybe)
10:21:01.902 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
10:21:01.902 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
10:21:01.902 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
10:21:01.903 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
10:21:01.903 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
10:21:01.904 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
10:21:01.904 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
10:21:01.914 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
10:21:01.922 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor - -Dio.netty.globalEventExecutor.quietPeriodSeconds: 1
10:21:01.930 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
10:21:01.930 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
10:21:01.934 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
10:21:01.935 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
10:21:01.947 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
10:21:03.210 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
10:21:03.211 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
10:21:03.211 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 17
10:21:03.211 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
10:21:03.213 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
10:21:03.213 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
10:21:03.213 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
10:21:03.213 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
10:21:03.213 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
10:21:03.214 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable: class io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @57a49ead
10:21:03.215 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
10:21:03.215 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
10:21:03.215 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 1073741824 bytes (maybe)
10:21:03.216 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
10:21:03.216 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
10:21:03.216 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
10:21:03.216 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
10:21:03.216 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
10:21:03.217 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
10:21:03.217 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
10:21:03.507 [pool-1-thread-1]
ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at io.gatling.app.SimulationClass$Scala.params(SimulationClass.scala:31)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.load(Runner.scala:72)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:57)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:89)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:51)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromSbtTestFramework(Gatling.scala:47)
        at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.liftedTree1$1(GatlingTask.scala:51)
        at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.execute(GatlingTask.scala:50)
        at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:414)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
        at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:264)
        at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Unary.<init>(builders.scala:27)
        at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Grpc.rpc(builders.scala:14)
        at test.scala.BasicSimu.<init>(BasicSimu.scala:39)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
10:21:03.580 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown - Running CoordinatedShutdown with reason [ActorSystemTerminateReason]
[error] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.SimulationClass$Scala.params(SimulationClass.scala:31)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Runner.load(Runner.scala:72)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:57)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:89)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:51)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromSbtTestFramework(Gatling.scala:47)
[error]         at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.liftedTree1$1(GatlingTask.scala:51)
[error]         at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.execute(GatlingTask.scala:50)
[error]         at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:414)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
[error]         at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:264)
[error]         at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Unary.<init>(builders.scala:27)
[error]         at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Grpc.rpc(builders.scala:14)
[error]         at test.scala.BasicSimu.<init>(BasicSimu.scala:39)
[error]         ... 18 more
[error] Simulation BasicSimu failed.
```

My parsing body pload

```
  val TokenKey : String = "key"
  val grpcConf = grpc(managedChannelBuilder(name = "request-url", port = 80)
                .usePlaintext())
                .header(util.BearerToken, optional = true)($(TokenKey))
  val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
      .exec(
        grpc("test")
          .rpc(RelayServerGrpc.METHOD_START_PAIRING)
          .payload(StartPairingRequest(Option(Device("labore non laborum id ea"))))
          .check(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
          )
```

The "Option" is the parent type of "Device", so I put in a full declare, hopefully it would not be related to the log error.

As I understand, there is a conflict between the libraries there, is there a suggestion what I should do on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can look at the stack trace and see which line threw the error.

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
[error]         at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:264)
[error]         at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Unary.<init>(builders.scala:27)
```

A decent IDE should bring you to that line with one single click.

https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/67eb5ea196d66db9e26be292df632be82329785a/src/main/scala/com/github/phisgr/gatling/grpc/request/builders.scala#L27

```scala
assert(method.getType == MethodDescriptor.MethodType.UNARY)
```

`.rpc` is for building a single-request-single-response gRPC call. You should use the appropriate [builder for streaming calls](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/67eb5ea196d66db9e26be292df632be82329785a/src/main/scala/com/github/phisgr/gatling/grpc/request/builders.scala#L16-L23) for your RPC.

---

Reading the stack trace is a basic skill in debugging JVM applications, I cannot tell whether this question comes from a lack of effort, or prior knowledge.

Comment: In my situation, I want to make a client stream to server to get some data back while keeping the streaming going, "clientStream" would be the appropriate one right ?

Comment: Because the complexity of my project and my limited knowledge, may I have your email or something so that I could make a sum up of current situation for you to understand ?

Comment: I don't do consulting, for free or otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment makes you feeling I'm asking for "consulting", but at the very least that I'm trying to understand things that I'm doing, to start with either Java, Kotlin or Scala was not my choice to pick in the first place, so I hope I could get some help and to be able to make some documentary for this later on.